# How to resolve vulnerable issues in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting like this error in my application:

> The application uses a dangerous regex pattern
> "/(?:\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g", at line 02 line number javascript
> code.

So How to resolve this vulnerable issue in regular expression? Any alternate method is there?

```
  var longline = "dddgjjb gah hjjjj \ fghjj hjjjjj"+"Dffjjhk";  
  var test=longline.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g, "<br />").replace(/(?:\\+)+/g,"");        // 02 line number 
  console.log(test);
```

Demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qdqjz3

Comment: It would greatly help your question to add a description about what the regex is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Try this snippet  `var test=longline.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g,'');` - The problem is due to putting regex inside double quotes.

Comment: @user2932057: Not working..again i am getting same issue